# How to test API PUT/POST request without GET method developed?

Tags: spring, api, testing

If I'm in a situation where the API has only PUT or POST method developed, how would one test that the PUT or POST request updated the information correctly in the database, for example? Trying to think from a QA perspective... once they submit a PUT request, how can they check to make sure that it updated correct fields with correct information, provided there is no GET method developed for said API?

Comment: They could go and look in the database? Or if you're writing automated tests, you can auto-wire access to the repository into a mock-MVC integration test (see e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html for the various provided testing functionality).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of writing some Java/JS to check the DB automatically. Was wondering if there may be a better way?

Comment: I'm also wondering how helpful is Fiddler or Postman going to be, capturing the response body of PUT/POST request... Maybe that would be sufficient for manual tests?

Comment: That just tells you how the server responded, not what went into the database. And you can automate that with mockMVC tests, as the answer below shows.

Comment: Better is relative because the good way is probably like @jonrsharpe said with mock-MVC. But, you could use like JDBCTemplate and create your query to retrieve the modified object to look up if the process was successful

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look into mockMVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write some integration test

like this:

```
 mvc.perform(post(REPORT_EVENT)

                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(getRequest(BASIC_JSON_PATH+"test.json"))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

then send request to db or check if needed data are in needed source.